# WPF- Treeview--How to add child nodes

Tags: wpf, treeview

i wanna populate treeview from database.
i have a table named Topics.

1.topicid
2.topicname
3.parentid

i am using access database. can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is too general, no one is going to do your work for you... please be more specific if you want answers

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a "HierarchicalDataTemplate" to use with your collection.  I agree with one of the commenters that your question is too general and feels like you need to take your own stab at this question first, but I'll point you in the right direction of a sample:
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/over-reaction-to-a-simple-wpf-explorer-tree/

Hope this helps.